# How do I mock a static method in moq.ts

Tags: typescript, mocking

A class exists:

```
export declare class MyLogger {
  static getInstance(id: string) : Logger;
}
```

The class to mock:

```
class Logger {
  error(message: string): Logger {
    // implementation...
  }
}
```

System under test has the following code:

```
class Sut {
  log = MyLogger.getInstance();
  testMethod() {
    this.log.error('Foo');
  }
}
```

How can I intercept the method and pass a mock logger back?

Something like:

```
const loggerMock = new Mock<MyLogger>();
loggerMock
  .setupStatic(()=>MyLogger.getInstance())
  .returns(loggerMock.object());

// assert call to `error()` method has parameter 'Foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best I've come up with:

```
const loggerMock = new Mock<Logger>();
const mockLoggerStaticMethod = jest.fn();
MyLogger.getInstance = mockLoggerStaticMethod;
mockLoggerStaticMethod.mockReturnValue(loggerMock.object());
```

How to get rid of the `jest.fn()` reference?